# Cordova 3.5 - Back button event firing in Android emulator but not firing in real android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, back-button

I'm using cordova 3.5 to develop an android application, I want to close the application when back button is pressed. I'm using the following code -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() { 
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
    };
    function backKeyDown(){
    if(confirm("Exit Application?")) {  
       navigator.app.exitApp();
    }    
    };
```

This code seems to work fine in android emulator and I get a confirm dialog when back button is pressed. But in real device, it just navigates back to previous page.

I tried preventDefault() also, still no use.
Someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed now, Previously while debugging i commented this line in cordova.js

```
return prompt(argsJson, 'gap:'+JSON.stringify([service, action, callbackId]));
```

Uncommenting the line fixed the problem.